# How to read Heroku logs in Cloud9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloud9-ide

My project is working well in Cloud9 but after deployed to Heroku, only the homepage and login page are working. When I try to access contact page (which is part of the same controller static_pages) or sign up page, Heroku retrieve "We're sorry, but something went wrong." then it says to check the log. But, there is a problem, I don't know how to check its logs through Cloud9 as well as when I try to add "Logentries" add on to my app on Heroku, it asks to me to create a bill account with them and I do not have a way to do it (I tried to open a trial with Google Cloud and Azure but it didn't work). So, please, does anyone know how to read the logs? Because if it is something in my code, I need to know. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing in your console:

```
heroku logs
```

Comment: I've tried this but I've got this as an answer:
`Permission bits for '/home/ubuntu/.netrc' should be 0600, but are 644.
You should run `chmod 0600 /home/ubuntu/.netrc` so that your credentials are NOT accessible by others.`

Comment: It didn't work after you run that command? "chmod 0600 /home/ubuntu/.netrc"